# read static files from servlet directory

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, netbeans

i want to tell my java servlet to ignore calls for static files, for example, if the file exists - just return the actual file without actually loading the servlet.

in my example i have a MyServlet in netbeans, and under the "web pages" directory i placed image.jpg.

next, i generated a .war file and placed it under tomcat/webapps

when i try to make a request to localhost:8080/MyServlet/image.jpg - the file is not loaded, the servlet is executed instead.

what i want is that if the file exists - it will return it, otherwise will run the servlet.

is there a quick way to implement it?

Comment: You mix up servlets and web applications. In general static content is served by a standard (container dependent) servlet and works without any modification. How does your servlet mapping look like (I suppose it's something like `/*`)?

Answer (score 3):

Mapping your servlet to `/` or `/*` is not the *standard way* for implementing servlets. In general you map global (controller) servlets to a path like `/myServlet/*`. Tomcat's default servlet is already available to serve your static content. It's configured in `<tomcat>/conf/web.xml`. Extract from inline documentation:

```
  <!-- The default servlet for all web applications, that serves static     -->
  <!-- resources.  It processes all requests that are not mapped to other   -->
  <!-- servlets with servlet mappings (defined either here or in your own   -->
```

If you follow the above mentioned approach URLs in your application may look like this:

Static resource: `http://myserver/myWAR/images/image.gif`

Your servlet's URLs: `http://myserver/myWAR/myServlet/*` (* := wildcard)

Of course, more complex options like offloading static content to an external web server are available. You can override the standard configuration as well, but in most situations this is not necessary (at least in my experience).

Answer (score 1):

Normally you'd handle this via your servlet mapping or by putting your static resources away from your servlet mapping.

Otherwise, if the request is mapping to your servlet, you either need to (a) check for the file in the servlet, and redirect to the real filename or stream back the image yourself, or (b) write a filter that knows enough about your webapp's structure to see if the request should be handled by your servlet, or the container.

If you described your usecase it'd be easier to be more helpful.

Comment: my servlet-mapping has url-pattern set to / , right now it seems like streaming the file is the solution

Answer (score 0):

For static files you most likely need just to use http://localhost:8080/image.jpg (i.e. without the MyServlet part in the URL)

Comment: Are you sure that you have placed image.jpg in the folder that web.xml indicates is the web root?